# Get pointer to data in Windows.AI.MachineLearning.TensorFloat from C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-machine-learning

I'd like to get a pointer to the data behind a `TensorFloat` in my C# .NET Core 5.0 application. I started by declaring `IMemoryBufferByteAccess`:

```cs
[ComImport]
[Guid("5b0d3235-4dba-4d44-865e-8f1d0e4fd04d")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
unsafe interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess
{
    void GetBuffer(out byte* buffer, out uint capacity);
}
```

Then, after the inference, I try to use it as follows:

```cs
var outputTensor = (TensorFloat)session.Evaluate(binding, "0").Outputs["myAwesomeOutput:0"];
using var outputReference = outputTensor.CreateReference();
((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)outputReference).GetBuffer(out var onnxOutput, out var onnxCapacity);
```

This results in an `System.InvalidCastException: 'Invalid cast from 'WinRT.IInspectable' to 'IMemoryBufferByteAccess'.'`, which is surprising, since the very same approach both for [Windows.Media](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/714722f53c3ae270f634f54cb2740411f6b11032/Samples/AudioCreation/cs/CustomEffect/CustomEffect.cs) and [Windows.Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging#create-or-edit-a-softwarebitmap-programmatically). The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.imemorybufferreference?view=winrt-19041#remarks) of Windows.Foundation.IMemoryBufferReference even states:

> The same object identity must also implement the COM interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess. A client retrieves the IMemoryBufferByteAccess interface pointer via a QueryInterface from the IMemoryBufferReference object.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. First I had to import an extension method:

```
using WinRT;
```

Then use the `As(...)` extension method to convert to `IMemoryBufferByteAccess` to retrieve the pointer:

```
outputReference.As<IMemoryBufferByteAccess>().GetBuffer(out var onnxOutput, out var onnxCapacity);
```