# Retreiving specific pixel color from a BitmapImage in WINUI application

Tags: winui-3, windows-11

I'm currently starting with an application using WinUI. It's about getting the color in a specific x,y coordinates of an image. I tried to use the `BitmapImage` to load the image. The problem is I don't have enough info on how to access it's pixel info like color. Anyone can help on this? thanks.

Expected result is to extract color of a specific pixel in an image using `BitmapImage` object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding specific pixel colors of a BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176910/finding-specific-pixel-colors-of-a-bitmapimage)

Comment: You could use WinRT's SoftwareBitmap instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap (and possibly WinUI3's SoftwareBitmapSource too) because it has buffer/pixel support (LockBuffer then WinRT's cast as IMemoryBufferByteAccess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147459/get-pointer-to-data-in-windows-ai-machinelearning-tensorfloat-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Use *WriteableBitmap*.

> A WriteableBitmap provides a BitmapSource that can be modified and
> that doesn't use the basic file-based decoding from the WIC. You can
> alter images dynamically and re-render the updated image.

See [Images and image brushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/images-imagebrushes#writeablebitmap) for more information, and

> [The IBuffer returned by WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer can't be written to directly. But
> you can use language-specific techniques to write to the underlying
> pixel content in the buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2#remarks).

[WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2#examples) code snippet which comes from [XAML images sample](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/XAML%20images%20sample) shows how to get pixel data.

```
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)) 
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream); 
    // Scale image to appropriate size 
    BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform() {  
        ScaledWidth = Convert.ToUInt32(Scenario4WriteableBitmap.PixelWidth), 
        ScaledHeight = Convert.ToUInt32(Scenario4WriteableBitmap.PixelHeight)
    }; 
    PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync( 
        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, // WriteableBitmap uses BGRA format 
        BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, 
        transform, 
        ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, // This sample ignores Exif orientation 
        ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage
    ); 

    // An array containing the decoded image data, which could be modified before being displayed 
    byte[] sourcePixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData(); 

    // Open a stream to copy the image contents to the WriteableBitmap's pixel buffer 
    using (Stream stream = Scenario4WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream()) 
    { 
        await stream.WriteAsync(sourcePixels, 0, sourcePixels.Length); 
    }                     
}
```